# Image not rendering in django template

Tags: django, image

I have an aws account where I upload all my images but when I go to try to render each image by doing die.image.url nothing happens. My code currently looks like this.

```
{% if dice %}
<div class="dice-container">
  {% for die in dice %}
  <div class="die-container">
    <img
      src="{{ die.image.url }}"
      alt="{{ die.name }}"
      width="100%"
    />
    <h6>{{ die.name }}</h6>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

my `Die` model has a field `image`. The name of each die comes out but the image not. How do I render the image?

Comment: Do you have a separate media folder? I have one in mine and it throws an error when I do not include `"/media/"` or a `"/static/"` before the `"{{ die.image.url }}"`.

Comment: So seems like i missed a configuration in my settings.py file. I have done uploading images before to aws and just realized my issue.